# Bresenham's algorithm drawing straight lines in all the octants

Tags: graphics, bresenham

I am currently taking an introductory course to graphics and I am learning about drawing straight lines using Bresenham's algorithm. Now I must confess that my studying habit involves google searching extra notes because sometimes in class notes just aren't enough.

I know that with a general Bresenham's algorithm you can in general draw the first octant and that in order to draw in the other octants you have to do some fancy tricks.

Now, my real question involves how to understand that concept behind drawing a line in the seventh octant. According to these notes

**https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/lecture/potts/lecture17_6pps.pdf**

that I found online (please refer to page 14 and 15 for more clarity in that pdf) if you want to draw in the seventh octant you have to swap the x1, y1 and x2,y2; then increment X by -1 and finally set the pixel as set_pixel(y,x). However, this is where my confusion is, on page 14 which shows an example of drawing in the seventh octant why is dx equal **positive 6 and not negative 6**? Isn't dx x2 - x1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distances are absolute values of the difference of coordinates. I think in [a later version of the same slides](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ECE390/lecture/Spring2006/Lecture19.pdf) (on slide 9), they changed it to `dx=|X2-X1|`, which is the correct notation.

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind this?

Comment: Link is dead now